# Changing class name

Tags: html, wordpress

Hello i am working on a menu in wordpress and made it dynamicly like this:

```
<?php wp_list_pages('sort_column=menu_order&depth=1&title_li=');?>
```

but when i look at my source i get the following:

```
<ul>
<li class="page_item page-item-5"><a href="http://localhost/private/Kife/?page_id=5" title="Start">Start</a></li>
<li class="page_item page-item-7"><a href="http://localhost/private/Kife/?page_id=7" title="Referenties">Referenties</a></li>
<li class="page_item page-item-9"><a href="http://localhost/private/Kife/?page_id=9" title="Over ons">Over ons</a></li>
<li class="page_item page-item-11"><a href="http://localhost/private/Kife/?page_id=11" title="Contact">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

What i would like to have is that the class names are the same as the title name? How would i do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately it's not possible using the `wp_list_pages()` function to add another class. You could do it afterwards using jquery, or script your own function in php that simulates `wp_list_pages()` the way you want it.

Do remember though that spaces in classes won't work.. you'll have to replace them with dashes or underscores (dashes are preferred, I believe)

Comment: And how would i replace the space? I have no idea where the class name comes from

Comment: The classname is generated by wordpress based on the article's number. If you create a new page the class will have page-item-12. It just counts up. Why do you need those specific classnames so badly? CSS? Because then you can just use `a[title="Over ons"]` etc. to style.

Answer (score 1):

Well.. you're going to want to slugify the title name at the very least.. but why would you want article-specific classes anyway? That won't scale well at all! Are you going to modify your style-sheet every time you write a new article? I can almost guarantee you're taking the wrong approach if this is what you want to do.

Comment: The links are in fact to basic pages (Home, About us, Contact, etc) which by the look of their names won't change often, so scalability is not a huge problem in this case.. though I do agree, this is not the best way to handle this.

Answer (score 0):

We've had to do this a couple of times. Though not pretty, its certainly not ugly. And, yes, there's a filter for that:

```
function my_page_css_class($class, $page) {
    if (!empty($page)) { // sanity check
        $class[] = sanitize_title($page->post_title);
    }
    return $class;
}
add_filter('page_css_class', 'my_page_css_class', 10, 2);
```